# Moving from large MS-Access database to a new platform

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, entity-framework, ms-access

Currently we have an application that uses a large MS Access database as the front end with a SQL Server back end. This has been the case for 10+ years and the Access database has become slow, unwieldy and difficult to maintain.

We are planning to create a new front end using a different platform. The plan is to create a basic framework in the software and then slowly move over each module one at a time into the new program over a period of 2-3 years.

Requirements

- Fast data entry – the biggest requirement, orders are taken over the
  phone and data entry needs to be as fast as possible.
- Report Generation – invoices, delivery notes, management reports.
- Links to EPOS devices and Accounts packages
- Future proof – as much as possible
- Potentially used on mobile devices and touch screens in the future
  for production/despatching/stock taking.
- Run on Windows platforms from XP onwards.

Experience

- Windows Forms
- VB.Net 3.5
- SQL Server

Given the requirements and our experience as a company I would like to know what people think would be the best technologies to use? Would you use Windows Forms? WPF? Entity Framework? .Net 4.0?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Hold up!: "Currently we have an application that uses a large MS Access database as the front end with a SQL Server back end. This has been the case for 10+ years and the Access database has become slow, unwieldy and difficult to maintain." - why has the front end become slow? It shouldn't need compacting, since the inserts/deletes are all happening in the SQL Server backend.

Comment: Also "over a period of 2-3 years. " : really? What's the longeveity of this app?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the back end used to be in MS Access until about 5 years ago when we moved to SQL Server. There are thousands of queries in the front end and hundreds of forms and reports.

Comment: The longevity of the app is hopefully as long as the current database has lasted, we plan to have them running side by side with the main functionality moved over to the new program. The stuff they do occasionaly will be left in the old database until we get round to moving it.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely like WPF over Forms.   XAML is a bit of a learning curve but for me easier to code and maintain.   If you have a large team (or even a small) consider MVVM.   No comment on EF.  Review your SQL table design as now if the time for any tuning.  And WCF - you are going 3 tier?